MacOS: I have a home directory within my home directory

I have never seen my home directory in my home directory until recently. Is this something I need to be worried about? I do not know if this is something problematic.

What's inside it? As Marcus has said, it's just a directory called ~ and was probably created by something/someone who quoted it (eg mkdir -p "~/foo"), thus preventing shell expansion. The contents might point towards the mechanism for creation.

There's a Desktop directory, and inside that a temp_chrome directory.

Try ls -ld ~/~

That's not your home directory, that's a directory with the name ~.
(the ~ being a shorthand for the content of $home is just something that exists because your shell invents it - it always gets translated to an actual path under the hood. Try print ~ to see what I mean – print doesn't do any path resolution, it's your shell that already expands ~ to the full path of your home directory before it passes it on to a function like print (or any other function).)
So, no, you don't need to worry. Chances are, that ended up there accidentally when you (or some other programmer) used a function that creates directories that are missing with something like ~/newfile; since only the shell expands ~ when you type it, that would just refer to a file in a directory literally called ~.
